# monit: Start or stop method not defined -- process sidekiq_site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, monit

I am using monit for sidekiq

while I am running the monit log file, it is showing the error.

```
monit: Start or stop method not defined -- process sidekiq_site
```

**sidekiq.erb**

```
check process sidekiq_site
    with pidfile /var/www/project/shared/pids/sidekiq.pid
    start program = "if [[ ! -f /var/www/project/shared/pids/sidekiq.pid ]]; then touch /var/www/project/shared/pids/sidekiq.pid; chmod 777  /var/www/project/shared/pids/sidekiq.pid; fi; cd /var/www/project/current ; bundle exec sidekiq --index 0 --pidfile /var/www/project/shared/pids/sidekiq.pid --environment production --logfile /var/www/project/shared/log/sidekiq.log --daemon" with timeout 90 seconds
    stop program = "if [ -d /var/www/project/current ] && [ -f /var/www/project/shared/pids/sidekiq.pid ] && kill -0 `cat /var/www/project/shared/pids/sidekiq.pid`> /dev/null 2>&1; then cd /var/www/project/current && bundle exec sidekiqctl stop /var/www/project/shared/pids/sidekiq.pid 1 ; else echo 'Sidekiq is not running'; fi"
    if totalmem is greater than 200 MB for 2 cycles then restart # eating up memory?
    group site_sidekiq
```

Comment: Sounds like it is looking for a process called "test". Worth checking on the server for any additional monit configuration (typically in /etc/monit/monitrc or /etc/monit/conf.d)

Comment: sorry It was not test, but the process name sidekiq_site .. And I have configured the monitrc in local app folder not in /etc/monit/monitrc file